# Обработка элемента select в html форме

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Простой пример. Пользователь вводит в поле ввода значение и выбирает из списка значение. Затем, они складываются. Не получается выбрать значение из списка. Что я не так делаю?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <input id="text" type="text" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="text">Введите число</label>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select id="number">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <label for="number">Выбирите число для сложения</label>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <br />
  <br />
  <button id="calculate" type="button">Расчитать</button>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button id="clear" type="reset">Очистить</button>
 </form>
 <p id="message"></p>
 <script>
  function funMessage() {
   var text = document.getElementById('text');
   var araNumber = document.getElementsByName('number');
   var message = document.getElementById('message');
   //перебираем массив
   for (var i=0; i<araNumber.length; i++) {
    //если option выбран
    if (araNumber[i].selected) {
     message.innerHTML = (parseFloat(text.value) + parseInt(araNumber[i].value));
    }
   }
  }
  function funClear() {
   message.innerHTML=null;
  }
  window.onload=function() {
   document.getElementById('calculate').onclick=funMessage;
   document.getElementById('clear').onclick=funClear;
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте это:

```
var araNumber = document.getElementsByName('number');
```

на это:

```
var araNumber = document.getElementById('number');
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Так и есть. Это моя невнимательность...